# npm package not working on vite project, but is working on vue-cli-service

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs3, vite

I have build a simple npm package, that got a single comoponent called MyButton

MyButton is written in vue 2 (2.7) + composition api so it can support both vue2 and vue3 projects.
After building for production and testing my library,
it works perfectly on all vue apps created using vue-cli-service, vue2 and vue3.
But, I have created a new project with vite + vue3.5.0 and I'm getting:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_c')`

But it seems not reasonable because Vue3 app created without vite is working perfectly.
What can causet this issue?

Comment: Maybe Vue demi could help you: https://antfu.me/posts/make-libraries-working-with-vue-2-and-3 and there https://github.com/vueuse/vue-demi

Comment: not exactly, but you helped me find my answer.
I forgot to add @vue/compat to allow compiling vue2 components.
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

OP fixed the issue by adding [@vue/compat](https://github.com/vuejs/core/tree/main/packages/vue-compat#readme) to the project.